# Only last wxStaticBitmap is showing

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

The same image is meant to be shown in different locations but only the second one is shown, why?

```cpp
void AppFrame::OnButtonClicked(wxCommandEvent& evt) {

    Tiles* knots = new Tiles(panel, 1);
    string tile = knots->firstTile();
    ImagePanel* drawPane = new ImagePanel(panel, tile, wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);

    wxStaticBitmap* image1 = new wxStaticBitmap(panel, wxID_ANY, drawPane->getImage(),wxPoint(Background::defaultStartX, Background::defaultStartY), wxSize(100, 100));
  
    wxStaticBitmap* image2 = new wxStaticBitmap(panel, wxID_ANY, drawPane->getImage(),wxPoint(Background::defaultStartX+100, Background::defaultStartY), wxSize(100, 100));

}
```

Comment: Read about sizers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't position your `ImagePanel` and depending on its size it can overlap the first bitmap. Generally speaking, using hard-coded position in pixels is **strongly** discouraged, you should let the controls use their natural size and position them using [sizers](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2.1/overview_sizer.html) as already mentioned in a comment.